# mock transaction in runTransaction

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin, ts-mockito

i want to mock code inside a [runTransaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) function.

example code:

```
await admin.firestore().runTransaction(async transaction => {
  const hubDocument = admin.firestore().collection("Acme").doc('4');
  const hubData = (await transaction.get(hubDocument)).data();
  newData = {
    ...hubData,
    someAttribute: 'some new value'
  };
  transaction.update(hubDocument, newData);
})
```

i want to mock `transaction`, check if it is called with the right data etc.pp.

I managed to mock `firestore()` but do not know how to mock the `transaction` parameter.

Comment: The "transaction" in this context is a [`Transaction` Object](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore_.html#~updateFunction) (runTransaction also allows for a [`TransactionOptions` Object](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore_.html#runTransaction) as an additional paramter). As far as I know the only paramters you'd need to mock inside a transaction are [`DocumentReference` and `DocumentData`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html). I don't think this fully answers your question, so please let me know how else I may assist you.

Comment: @fabc I pass the firebase object, so i can mock that. But i still have no idea how to mock it in order that runTransaction passes my transaction mock.

Comment: Maybe yeou can find a solution with npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/firestore-jest-mock#firestoretransaction

Comment: What does your transaction mock look like, currently? (also, excellent suggestion by @FiodorovAndrei )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tested this, but I asume something like this should do the trick:

```
import { Transaction } from '@google-cloud/firestore';

const origTransactionGet = Transaction.prototype.get
Transaction.prototype.get = function () {
   console.log(arguments, "< Intercepted Transaction.prototype.get")
   return origTransactionGet.apply(this, arguments)
}

// your code
await admin.firestore().runTransaction(async transaction => {
  const hubDocument = admin.firestore().collection("Acme").doc('4');
  const hubData = (await transaction.get(hubDocument)).data();
  newData = {
    ...hubData,
    someAttribute: 'some new value'
  };
  transaction.update(hubDocument, newData);
})
```

As @FiodorovAndrei commented, the alternative, perhaps more comfortable if you use `jest` would be to just use [firestore-jest-mock](https://github.com/Upstatement/firestore-jest-mock) to mock the Firestore functionality.